# How to fix timeUnit error in Altair chart

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I'm trying to plot a time series chart in Altair, and the x-axis does not display as wanted. The timeUnit option set all my observation on the same x-axis point.

I have a dataset that where looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2011, 2012], 'value': [5000, 10000]})

Out:
    year    value
0   2011    5000
1   2012    10000
```

And I would like to plot a time series of value. I have tried to use the timeUnit option as following:

```
import altair as alt

alt.Chart(data).mark_line(point = True).encode(
    x = alt.X('year:T',
             timeUnit = 'year'),
    y = alt.Y('value:Q')
)
```

But it does not display correctly the x-axis: [chart_option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi3Qc.png). If I remove the timeUnit option, it does not help much: [chart_no_option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWapP.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an integer value to a temporal encoding, it treats it as a unix timestamp (i.e. milliseconds since January 1 1970).

If you want to construct a datetime object from integer years, you can do so by preprocessing the data with pandas to create a DateTime column:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2011, 2012], 'value': [5000, 10000]})
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['year'], format='%Y')

alt.Chart(data).mark_line(point = True).encode(
    x = alt.X('date:T', timeUnit = 'year'),
    y = alt.Y('value:Q')
)
```

or if you would like to avoid preprocessing the data, you can use a calculate transform directly within Altair:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2011, 2012], 'value': [5000, 10000]})

alt.Chart(data).transform_calculate(
    date='datetime(datum.year, 1, 1)'  # (year, month, date)
).mark_line(point = True).encode(
    x = alt.X('date:T', timeUnit = 'year'),
    y = alt.Y('value:Q')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand the process now. However, I'm kind of surprised by the result. I was expecting two values for x-axis labels. Instead 2011 and 2012 appear multiple times. Isn't the timeUnit option suppose to handle this case?

Comment: If you use ``timeunit='yearmonth'`` or `'yearmonthdate'` then the axis will be more meaningfully labeled. Alternatively, if you care about the year as an ordered category rather than a point in continuous time, you can use ``date:O`` rather than ``date:T``.

Comment: Hmm, it was not what I was looking for because there was too many tick. I adjust for it by using the tickCount option: 
data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2011, 2012], 'value': [5000, 10000]})
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['year'], format='%Y')

alt.Chart(data).mark_line(point = True).encode(
    x = alt.X('date:T', timeUnit = 'year', axis = alt.Axis(tickCount = 2)),
    y = alt.Y('value:Q')
)
I guess there is a more efficient way to do it, but thanks!